# Fetch details of a field of a Doc referenced by an ID

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Please consider this UI to display snippets of a transaction item in a List:

```
UI

|-  -   -   -   -   -   -   |
|                           |
|   Transaction             |
|                           |
|   title   "Bought food"   |
|   tags    [online, food]  |
|   vault   "bankA"         |
|                           |
|   -   -   -   -   -   -   |
```

I structured the data as a Root level collection as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#root-level_collections):

```
Data structure:
-- Root
    -- (collection) Users
        -- (doc) userA:
            -- name: User Name
            -- ... other fields
    -- (collection) Tags
        -- (doc) tagA:
            -- title: online
            -- user_id: userA
            -- ... other fields
        -- (doc) tagB:
            -- title: food
            -- user_id: userA
            -- ... other fields
    -- (collection) Vaults
        -- (doc) vaultA:
            -- title: bankA
            -- user_id: userA
            -- ... other fields
    -- (collection) Transactions
        -- (doc) transactionA
            -- user_id: userA
            -- title: "Bought food"
            -- tags: [tagA, tagB]
            -- vault_id: vaultA
            -- ... other fields
```

When I am fetching the transactions via `getDocs()`:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "transactions"));
```

How can I also get the other details (tag title from tags and vault title) of the fields for a transaction? Do I have to fetch each doc again from their respective ids for the details?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a separate query for each additional data that exist in another collection.

Comment: @AlexMamo Okay. Do you think it would be better if I store the required details for the transaction as map with its id and actual value (eg: user: {user_id: userA, value: User Name}). And later when updating the document, update all the document with batch writes?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. If it fits your query and use-case of your app, why not?